# OrderByDescending doesn't work in nested linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

In Linqpad, i can see the correct list. But in code, after  putting in the list collection, order by doesn't work for BeginDate. If i use BeginDate with Max, it works. I don't understand where i am wrong?

```
            var templist =  contentRepository
                       .Get(q => (q.Status == (int)StatusEnum.Active) &&     
                           (q.CategoryId == category.GetHashCode() || q.Category.ParentId == category.GetHashCode())                   
                           && q.MinorVersion == 0
                           && q.MajorVersion > 0) 
                       .GroupBy(q => q.VersionId)
                       .OrderByDescending(q => q.Key)
                       .Select(q => new 
                       {
                           VersionId        = q.Key,
                           Id               = q.Max(x => x.Id),
                           MajorVersion     = q.Max(x => x.MajorVersion), 
                           UpdatedAt        = q.Max(x => x.UpdatedAt), 
                           //BeginDate        = q.Max(x=>x.BeginDate),
                           BeginDate        = (q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1).Select(x=>x.BeginDate)).First(),
                           Title = (q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1).Select(x => x.Title)).First(),
                           ShowOnHomePage   = (q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1).Select(x=>x.ShowOnHomePage)).First()
                        })
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.BeginDate)                           
                       .Take(maxItemCount)
                       .ToList();

            List<ContentEntity> contents = new List<ContentEntity>();

        templist.ForEach(q => contents.Add(
                                         contentRepository
                                        .Get(x => x.VersionId == q.VersionId && x.MajorVersion == q.MajorVersion && x.MinorVersion == 0)
                                        .FirstOrDefault()                                        
                                        ));


        return contents.Where(q => q.ShowOnHomePage == true)
                       .OrderByDescending(q => q.MajorVersion)
                       .OrderByDescending(q => q.BeginDate)
                       .Take(maxItemCount)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: What **doesn't work** means? Exception?

Comment: Order by is not working. Dates come as random in list. Not ordered. But this one BeginDate        = q.Max(x=>x.BeginDate) 
is ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You are ordering by `Id`, not by `BeginDate`. Equivalent code for

```
q.Max(x => x.BeginDate)
```

Will be

```
q.OrderByDescending(x => x.BeginDate).Take(1).Select(x => x.BeginDate).First()
```

Or simplified

```
q.OrderByDescending(x => x.BeginDate).First().BeginDate
```

Comment: But i want to take the latest record for BeginDate. There is a group by. So it should be ordered by Id. Your answer gives me a result which i have already got it.

Comment: @Bora my answer points on reason why you have different results. From your question it's not clear what is your expected resulsts

Comment: BeginDate        = (q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1).Select(x=>x.BeginDate)).First()

It doesn't give any meaningfull result.
But i have to take the Id because of latest record. There is a group by. Normally when i use Max, it's okey but it gives me max date. But it doesnt mean rhe latest record must be the latest date. So **bold**I take  the latest Id then take its date**bold**

I realize it's not so clear. Sorry about that. i'm trying to be more clear as much as i can.

Comment: `q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First().BeginDate` should return date of entity with max id. BTW is it enity framework or linq to sql?

Comment: This is LLBLGEN Orm code generator. We use with a repository pattern. It works when i changed like that contentRepository.Get(null).Where(...). And your code is absolutely it what i need. Thank you!